# Modular arithmetic: $P \cdot Q^{-1} \mod p$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am reading an explanation to a programming competition, where one of the step is to calculate $P \cdot Q^{-1} \mod p$, where p is a prime.

I was always doing this by calculating [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $Q$ modulo $p$ by using extended Euclidean algorithm and then using $(A \cdot B) \mod p = ((A \mod p) \cdot (B \mod p)) \mod p$, which works just fine.

But in the explanation they present another approach:

> Calculating multiplicative inverse $P \cdot Q^{-1}$ in the ring of integers modulo prime integer $p$ can be done by well-known formula $P \cdot Q^{p - 2}$

which looks more appealing to me, because the time complexity is the same, but it is easier to code.

---

So how can one prove this, and what is the point of using multiplicative inverse if one can use an easier formula?

Comment: If we use some version of the binary method of modular exponentiation, performance is reasonably good. But average case performance of the extended Euclidean algorithm is better.

Comment: @AndréNicolas yes, I assumed the modular exponentiation method that runs in `O(log exp)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fermat's little theorem says that
$$Q^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$$

Multiply this by $Q^{-1}$ and you are done.

The problem is that $Q^ {p-2}$ can be not-so-easy to compute, if $p$ is big. Extended Euclidean may be more efficient.

Comment: Are you sure about efficiency? In the worst case Euclidean algorithm reduces the length of the numbers by one (decimal) digit in five iterations. Square-and-multiply calculation of $Q^{p-2}$ reduces the exponent approximately by half per 1-2 multiplications (depending on the value of the bit in the exponent). To get more precise figures more careful analysis of the elementary operations and their respective complexities. I don't know the answer, but the difference may not as clear cut as one might initially think. I don't know te answer, that's why I'm commenting :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: For the Euclidean algorithm, worst case you reduce the size of the inputs by a factor of $2$ every 2 steps, so worst case it would take $\min(2 \log_2(p), 2\log Q + 1)$ steps, but it has the potential to run significantly faster.  For exponentiation by squaring, it always takes between $\log_2 (p-2)$ and $2\log_2 (p-2)$ steps.  So assuming that $Q$ isn't substantially smaller than $p$, the two algorithms have the same worst case run time, but the Euclidean algorithm has significantly better best-case (and possibly better average-case) runtime. However, it requires more storage.